# C has "partial" function like Python?

Tags: python, c, function, pointers, arguments

Python has a [partial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html#functools.partial) function, like the example below:

```
func = partial(anyFunction, "some_argument")
turtle.Screen().onkey(func, "Up")
```

Thus, I can use arguments in a function I am passing as argument.

In C language there is something similar?
I need it because in a certain function has as its parameter the pointer to another function. I need to pass an argument to this function. As in the case below:

```
void test(int value) {
    printf("Value: %d\n", value);
}

void test2() {
    printf("Test2!\n");
}

void makeYNQuestion(char question[], const void *yesFunction, const void* noFunction) {
    [...]
}

makeYNQuestion("my question", &test, &test2);
```

Need to pass some value to the test. How to solve this?